# How to close the automatic creation of time series with FLOAT data type in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

If the time series has already been created and deleted in Apache IoTDB, and when I tried to create it again, the time series with FLOAT data type will be automatically created. Is this a bug or a setting that can be changed? If it is a setting, how can I close this automatic setting in IoTDB?

how to deal this question,someone help please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This automatic metadata creation with FLOAT data type is because of `enable_auto_create_schema` parameter setting in Apache IoTDB. The automatic creation of metadata is for better prediction and expansion of your time series structure.
This is not a bug and you can still manage your original time series.